# MySQL Join Wrong Result

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables, Name, Supervisor and Manager. I need a query that displays a list of names and whether they are supervisors, managers, or both.

My current query accomplished 90% of the problem, returns all those that are  supervisors, and checks if they are also manager or not. However, if the user is not a "Supervisor" but is a "Manager" than he is not listed on the query.

```
SELECT name.id,
name.email,
IF(sup.code = 1, 'Yes', 'No') as Supervisor,
IF(man.userId IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') as Manager
FROM employee name
LEFT JOIN supervisor sup ON name.id = sup.id
LEFT JOIN manager man ON name.id = man.id
WHERE sup.code = 1
```

Thank you

Comment: You are left joining table `supervisor`, so presumably if a person is not a supervisor, they don't have a record in `supervisor`. In that case `sup.code` won't be 1

Comment: Have you tried leaving the `WHERE` clause out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `where` clause. By including that, you are limiting your results to only include those that have that value set. Obviously this wont be true for those who are not supervisors.

This breaks the `outernish` of your join. To have additional conditions on a left join, without breaking that functionality, you need to move the criteria to the `on` clause.  In this case, it looks like you could also just remove the `where` clause entirely, unless there is possibly more than one entry in the supervisor table for each employee.

Anyway, your two choices are:

```
SELECT name.id,
name.email,
IF(sup.code = 1, 'Yes', 'No') as Supervisor,
IF(man.userId IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') as Manager
FROM employee name
LEFT JOIN supervisor sup ON name.id = sup.id
LEFT JOIN manager man ON name.id = man.id
```

And:

```
SELECT name.id,
name.email,
IF(sup.code = 1, 'Yes', 'No') as Supervisor,
IF(man.userId IS NOT NULL, 'Yes', 'No') as Manager
FROM employee name
LEFT JOIN supervisor sup ON name.id = sup.id AND sup.code = 1
LEFT JOIN manager man ON name.id = man.id
```

Comment: Thank you @pala_ 
I modified your answer (adding the AND condition to the Join) and maitained the WHERE clause so that way i can filter out records that are "No" for both sup and manager, which i am not interested in seeing.